# How to avoid interference of HttpServletRequest.getReader and getParameterValues?

Tags: java, servlets

In my application I have to extract parameters of a request and put into a collection in the order of their appearance in the querystring.

For example, if the sender makes following request,

http://myapp.com/myrequest?param3=value3&param2=value2&param1=value1 ,

I need to generate a collection, in which the elements are placed in this order: param3, param2, param1.

To achieve this, I first extract the names of the parameters using the method `getParameterNames` shown below.

```
private List<String> getParameterNames(HttpServletRequest aRequest) 
  throws IOException {
    final List<String> parameterNames = new LinkedList<>();
    final BufferedReader reader = aRequest.getReader();
    final String queryString = IOUtils.toString(reader);

    final String[] parameterValuePairs = queryString.split("&");

    for (String parameterValuePair : parameterValuePairs) {
        final String[] nameValueArray = parameterValuePair.split("=");

        parameterNames.add(nameValueArray[0]);
    }
    return parameterNames;
}
```

The problem: After invokation of this method, `aRequest.getParameterValue(...)` returns `null` for ever parameter name.

If I do it otherwise - first save the parameter map, and then invoke `getParameterNames`, then its result is null.

```
final Map<String,String[]> parameterMap = aRequest.getParameterMap();
final List<String> parameterNames = getParameterNames(aRequest);
```

I tried following things:

1. Make sure that `reader.close()` is not invoked in `getParameterNames` (elsewhere I read that this may cause problems).
2. Invoke `reader.reset()`.

None of this helped.

How can I get a list of parameter-value pairs from a `HttpServletRequest`, which is sorted by parameter's appearance in the querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first approach you don't need to use `Reader` to get the parameters. Instead do:

```
final List<String> parameterNames = new LinkedList<>();
final String queryString = query.getQueryString(); // get query string from query itself
// rest of your code stays unchanged
```

The reason it didn't work is because data from a request input stream can be read only once.

Or, if I am wrong and that is not the case, you can save parameters and their values into a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
final LinkedHashMap<String, String> parameterValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
final BufferedReader reader = aRequest.getReader();
final String queryString = IOUtils.toString(reader);

final String[] parameterValuePairs = queryString.split("&");

for (String parameterValuePair : parameterValuePairs) {
    final String[] nameValueArray = parameterValuePair.split("=");
    parameterValues.put(nameValueArray[0], nameValueArray[1]);
}
```

Now `parameterValues` is a map with entries sorted by the order of appearance.